# if statement in HTML in ionic 3

Tags: html, typescript, ionic-framework

i am using ionic 3.9 , i have a button in my HTML file i want to make a conditional if statement that according to the value of a variable from the typescript if it's true it will display a button text if not it will display another text .
this is the button :

```
  <button ion-button (click)="openCalendar()">Me Rapeller de cet evenement </button>
```

i want it to be like this :

```
  <button ion-button (click)="openCalendar()">
   if(this.traduction == true){
Me Rapeller de cet evenement
   }else{
Remind me later
   }
 </button>
```

is that possible in HTML ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an ionic question but an angular one and yes it is possible.

```
 <button ion-button (click)="openCalendar()">
  {{getText()}}
 </button>
```

And in your component file

```
 getText() {
  if(this.traduction === true){
    return 'Me Rapeller de cet evenement';
   } else {
     return 'Remind me later';
   }
}
```

However instead of coding like this I would suggest looking at i18n functionality in Angular.

https://angular.io/guide/i18n